# How to get a dataset within RDL report file to decrypt and rebind to it?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdl

Few of data columns coming in my report are encrypted, I want to get dataset/datatable from rdl file at runtime to decrypt the records and rebind it to report?

I am using reportviewer on Asp.net page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have same problem like me , I made a class library project to decrypt the data, created a DLL. Referenced that DLL in my RDL file and called that decrypt method in encrypted column of report. Here is the reference how to do:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920769/how-to-use-custom-assemblies-or-embedded-code-in-reporting-services